# Internet Explorer 10 not showing custom cursor on Windows 8

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the mouse cursor in a cross-browser HTML5 webapp.
By simply adding the appropriate CSS everything works fine in all browsers, including IE on Windows 7.

The same webapp in Windows 8 fails to change the cursor, although by inspecting the CSS I can see that the correct class is applied and the browser queries the server for the appropriate .cur file.

Is there any limitation on Windows 8 that I should be aware of?

**EDIT**

CSS example (note: this works on IE10 Win7, does not work on IE10 Win8. The example should be irrelevant given the question).

```
.customCursor-move {
   cursor: url(/free/images/pointers/move.cur),url(free/images/pointers/move.cur),url("../images/pointers/move.cur"),  default !important;
}
```

The CSS is in free/css.

Comment: Could you add the rendered CSS?

Comment: CSS added, although I'm fairly sure an example won't help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the URL relative to the _page_, not to the CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer `cursor` css property is buggy : 
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

It could also include IE10. You should try wether to use an absolute or relative path to your `.cur` file , depending of what you have now.

it also might be helpful :

> Note also that the Windows operating system requires the image to be 32 x 32 pixels or smaller although the specifications do allow for larger sizes than this.

Comment: I love the fact that it says "it must be that size, but not really".

Comment: Yes it is almost quite fun. But it is still anoying. On this one, I would simply forget it, and wait the day M$ debug this property, or not.