# mousedown and cursor Events Not Firing

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am using the mouse-down and mouse-up jQuery events to change my cursor in these cases. This seems to work in all browsers except for IE 10 and 11. I couldn't find any resource that would say why that won't work or a replacement for these event. Any help ?

```
$("#element").mousedown(function(){
     $(this).css("cursor" , "move");
}).mouseup(function(){
     $(this).css("cursor" , "default");
});
```

Comment: Internet Explorer `cursor` css property is buggy: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17694522/4532601).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following markup in IE 11 and it worked as expected:

```js
  $(function () {
    $("#div1").mousedown(function () {
      $(this).css("cursor", "move");
    }).mouseup(function () {
      $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container body-content">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Ensure that the events are being attached to the element?

Comment: Yeah same code is working fine on chrome , Firefox , safari and IE 9.
I don't think it's a cursor problem cause when I debug the code for some reason the mousedown function isn't even accessed.